# Automatic Reference Counting on iOS 3.x

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

Does an app compiled with arc turned on work with iOS 3.1.x devices?  Ideally I would like to make our app work only with iOS 4.x and higher but we have some users still running iOS 3.x. I no longer have access to devices with iOS 3.

Has anyone tested?

Comment: I've developed a simple app using ARC that only display a UITableView with 10 rows. It works on my iPhone 3G running iOS 3.0.

Comment: This SO question and answer also confirm that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646607/arc-works-for-ios-3-x-what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't count on ARC working back to iOS 3.x until you've at least found official documentation to that effect and perhaps tested it yourself as well. Here's [at least one opinion that supports the notion that apps written using ARC may not even work on all versions of iOS 4](http://hackerne.ws/item?id=3044685).

Answer (score 3):

ARC is only available on iOS 4.0 and above.  Additionally automatic real reference nil-ing is only available on iOS 5.0 and above.

Comment: +1 I thought that was the case too, but had a hard time finding it documented. If you can add a link to a reference, it might help others in the future.

Comment: I've successfully ran several apps with ARC enabled (and in use) on my iPhone 3G running iOS 4.2.1. The same apps also ran on my iPad 1 with iOS 4.2. Apple only states that weak references (probably referring to the "weak" @property attribute) is not available on iOS 4. See Transitioning to ARC Release Notes: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Comment: This is bad information. I've just successfully installed and run an ARC app on devices running iOS 4.0.2 and iOS 4.2.1. It doesn't seem to work on 3.x though.

Comment: @grahamparks I have updated.  I think the issue is that Apple typically states support only for the last release of a previous major OS version.  That does not necessarily mean that earlier versions are not supported.  In the Case of ARC Apple seems only to require iOS 4.0 in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the deployment target to pre 5.0 the compiler will automatically insert the memory management (retain/release) for you. So yes, it will work.

Comment: The question is wether or not ARC would work om iOS 3. It won't.