# How does my ARC app work in iOS 3.x?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

So I just found out that ARC is only supported for devices running iOS 4.0+.

How does my app (in the store) work on devices running iOS 3.0 then (definitely using ARC)?

I'm so confused.

**Solution from below: As long as I don't use zeroing weak references it seems that using ARC still works with iOS 3.x, but Apple just has not guaranteed the result.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ARC is mostly a compile time feature, the compiler inserts the appropiate `release` calls. AFAIK only zeroing weak references need runtime support. So as longs as you don't use those you're on thin ice, but it can work.

Comment: Hmm okay. Thanks for clearing that up. I'd upvote but I don't have the minimum yet.

Comment: Check the [Release notes on ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Because ARC works at compile time so you can link with SDK 5.0 and support iOS 4.0 if you want. The app will crash on 4.0 if you use any function that's been intruduced on 5.0.

Comment: Nah, you have to compile ARC app's to 4.0, but they'll work on 3.0 until you call a function of a more recent SDK, Just like DarkDust explained.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't read your answer properly - you said that it on 4.0 will crash if 5.0 functions are used. My bad - that's true - not really relevant to OP's question though :)

Comment: Just giving as an example, basically ARC works at compile time,so, no problem there. The problem is with possible non-existent functions at runtime.