# XCode Automatic Reference Count (ARC) on OS 3.0

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am using iOS SDK 5.1 , Xcode 4.3.3. And developing a project with Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) turned ON. I've read that ARC only works on iOS 4 or higher versions. But when I set deployment target to OS 3.0 , project still compiles fine. And I'm using a device with iOS 4.0 to test, and this application works fine on that device too.

My question is will this app work on a OS 3.0 actual device as well? (with ARC on).

And if it works why apple says it only works on iOS 4 or higher?

Comment: I think the project would compile since you're not adding anything new, but none of the release calls would be put automatically for you, so it's possible that you're leaking every object you create using alloc,copy, retain

Comment: [It depends on your code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646607/how-does-my-arc-app-work-in-ios-3-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't use `__weak` variables, your code should work fine. ARC code compiles down to regular MRC code under the hood, it just takes care of the `retain`/`release`/`autorelease` code for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if I use weak variables? will it still compile and leak memory at runtime?

Comment: I just tested. __weak variables doesn't compile. if I'm not using __weak variables at all, is it completely OK to use ARC on a project and deploy it to OS 3.0 ? Doing so will leak memory at runtime?

Comment: @Sleepwalkerfx no. Your code will compile and run fine on iOS 3.x devices, as ARC is just an additional layer added on by the compiler.