# tableview memory management - singleton class

Tags: ios, networking, singleton, paging, tableview

I am newbie on ios programming, so I have a question. I am working on an app, will continue to load data on internet, it's paging data, so when the user navigate to the next page, it will load the data of the page on the internet. I use a singleton class to make it, it works fine, but I had a question -

When the first page is arrival I save it to self.posts variable like - `self.posts = dataA`, and when the user go for the next page, it will change self.posts to dataB, like `self.posts = dataB`. my question is, if the dataA will be released by iOS automatically, or it's not? if it's not, how to deal with these garbage memory? You know it will load data page by page, if so many pages being loaded, it might be a problem......Thanks.

Sorry forget to tell you guys, the app is for iOS 3.x+, so I guess ARC is not available. Check this function, it will be called after the HTTP connection is done and will parse JSON to NSDictionary, each time it will load about 5 posts for a page, and next page is another 5 posts, so you know, the self.posts changed if it's another new HTTP networking.

```
- (void) getNextPostsFromJson:(NSData *)data
{
    NSError *theError = nil;

    NSDictionary *dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:data error:&theError];

    if (dict == nil) {
        isValidJson = NO;
        httpStatus = HTTP_STATUS_FAILED;

        NSLog(@"json con - %@ %@",
              [theError localizedDescription],
              [[theError userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);   
    } else {

        NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];        

        if ([keys count] >= TOTAL_SECTIONS) {
            self.posts = dict;
        } else {
            self.posts = nil;
        }

        NSLog(@"posts = %@", self.posts);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ARC in your project?

Comment: Provide some code or give us some details about `self.posts` and `dataA` (or `dataB`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Toaster** suggestion is right.

If you use a property like the following.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary* posts;
```

when you do

```
self.posts = dataB;
```

the old value referenced object is released for you.

The setter synthesized by the compiler using `@synthesize` directive looks like this (pseudo code here):

```
- (void)setPosts:(NSDictionary*)newPosts
{
    if(newDict != posts) {

        [newPosts retain]; // retain the new value
        [posts release]; // release the old value
        posts = newPosts; // now posts reference the new value
    }
}
```

**A simple suggestion for you.**

If you do `self.posts = dataB` you lose `dataA`. So when you came back, you need to perform the download again. So, what do you think to have a cache of downloaded data? For example create a `NSMutableDictionary` where each key is the page (the number of the page or whatever you like) and each value is the data (`dataA`, `dataB` and so on). Through it, you can avoid to download data each time. Maybe you can also set up a limit for this cache (say 5 data) to prevent memory issues.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It will be released automatically if you use ARC(automatic reference counting) and any other pointer (`_strong`) point to it. So don't worry :)

Comment: Thanks for you such quick answer, I actually make it to working across iOS 3.0+, I heard APC is not available on iOS 3.x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706889/automatic-reference-counting-on-ios-3-x, so any more advices?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you didn't retain dataA manually in addition to setting your property, you don't need to worry about it. Using dot-notation will cause the object set as the property to be retained and to be released again once it is being replaced by some other object.

**Edit:** the code example you added seems fine to me...

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation, very appreciate it! I will choose Flex_Addicted's answer, your answer is great, just I am thinking Flex_Addicted's answer is more details, so maybe more helpful for others.